# How to resize Image to specific size in android layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a image button  and I want to give the specific width and height to it, but my image size 512 x 512 and when activity starts layout is distorted because of the image.

Is there anyway I can resize it to some specific size?

```
                   <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/go_prev"
            />
```

Comment: Use android:layout_width and android:layout_height to set the width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Set your layout_width and layout_height to numeric values and it will fix the image to that exact size.  You can then control how its scaled or cropped vi the scaleType parameter.  Be careful specifying dp or px-  dp will let you specify it in 160ths of an inch, px will be phyiscal pixels (but may be any real world size).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the size in `px` which will be physical pixels instead of `dp` (Density-independent pixel); **However**, you should **not** do this if your app should support multiple screens.

Also, consider using `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` instead of `height` and `width`